# Split causes "Object doesn't support this property or method" exception

Tags: javascript, jquery

call to `split` on a variable causes a *"Object doesn't support this property or method"* exception and I don't know why.
Here's my code:

```
function getKontaktPersonen(kontaktSelectBox) {
   var kontaktPersonen = [];
   var id_and_name = kontaktSelectBox.attr('id');
   var id_part = getID_PartFromName(id_and_name);
   var textboxname;
   var selectboxname;
   if (kontaktSelectBox.attr('class') == 'kontaktSelectBox') {

        textboxname = "TextBoxKunde" + id_part;
        selectboxname = "SelectBoxKontaktPerson" + id_part;
    } else if (kontaktSelectBox.attr('class') == 'NewkontaktSelectBox') {
        textboxname = "NewTextBoxKunde" + id_part;
        selectboxname = "NewSelectBoxKontaktPerson" + id_part;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    var kundeBox = $('#' + textboxname);
    var kundeBoxVal = kundeBox.val();
    if (kundeBoxVal != '' && kundeBoxVal != null) {
     var adr_id = kundeBoxVal.split(';')[1];
      //here comes an ajax call
      //[...]
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure that it is not null

Comment: @Luke. What version? Try the code in Chrome or FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the selector didn't find any element the `val` function will return `undefined` Try this:

```
if (kundeBoxVal) {
     var adr_id = kundeBoxVal.split(';')[1];
 }
```

Comment: He is checking `kundeBoxVal != null` and since `null == undefined` that should cover this case.

Comment: ok. the value was undefined. Now I need to find out why. But that's another story.